# Adding an auto message to “Order comments” field in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, comments, orders

I have a product with 5 variables. I try to add  to each ordered variable an auto message to “Order comments” field.
e.g., if the customer ordered variable A, then the message XXXXX  will be automatically added to “order comments” field,
if the customer ordered variable B, then the message YYYYYYY will be automatically added to “order comments” field and so on for other variables.
I mean to customer order note\comment fiekd that display in order form below namae and address fields
Thanks

Comment: _"I need a code snippet for the following:"_. Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. Pure code-writing requests and/or recommendations to find a book, tool, software library or other off-site resource are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), we expect questions here to relate to specific programming problems. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to show [what you have tried so far to solve your problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 0):

You could start from here by adding your custom notes inside order page

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'add_engraving_notes' );
function add_engraving_notes( $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    // The text for the note
    $note = 'your message here';
    // Add the note
    $order->add_order_note( $note, true );
    // Save the data
    $order->save();
}
```

hope that helps, in order to start your goal

Comment: NO, does no work for me, the comment shows but not in the right place. Now the comment shows in the left column where all other comments in admin order page, but I need it to show in the note\comment field in the form that the the customer fills with his details such as name and address etc. plus I need 4 different messages, one for each product variable. Many Thanks